# Integrating over sums.

Tags: integration, summation

I want to make an integral. I know that Integral and Sum can be exchanged. But if I have the following case?

$$ \int\left(\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2}e^{ix}\right)\sum_{j_1}\sum_{j_2}e^{jx}\,\text dx $$

What is happening in this case?
I mean its not only an integral over a sum, but an integral over a multiplication of double sums.

ps, I am sorry, I do not know how to use here the symbols you use.

How I can do that integral?

Comment: @Tim thanks a lot Tim

Comment: What are the restrictions on $i_1, i_2, j_1, j_2$?  Are there any limits of integration?

Comment: i1,i2,j1,j2 go from zero to 10 for example. Yes, they are bounded.

Comment: I'm confused.  You have $i$ and $j$ in the exponents.  How do these relate to $i_1, i_2, j_1, j_2$?  I'd expect those variables to appear there instead.  Unless your summation indices are $i$ and $j$, and you're summing from $i=0...i_1$, $i=0...i_2$, $j=0...j_1$, $j=0...j_2$?

Comment: Yes, Actually their product. that is j=j1*j2. My mistake I didn't mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the sums are finite, then the product of double sums

$$ \left(\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2} e^{ix} \right)\left(\sum_{j_1}\sum_{j_2} e^{jx} \right)$$

is actually just the sum of all the cross-terms, ie

$$\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2}\sum_{j_1}\sum_{j_2} e^{ix} e^{jx} $$

and so you can then move the integral inside this giant sum to get

$$\sum_{i_1}\sum_{i_2}\sum_{j_1}\sum_{j_2} \int e^{(i+j)x}$$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Voting it as best answer